# TcpClient always got ReceiveBufferSize = 65536 on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

I created a NetworkStream object and read bytes matches TcpClient's ReceiveBufferSize. It worked fine on Windows 7 but seemed have problems on Windows 8.1. As a result, I had to make my buffer size large enough, such as 65536 as title.

I don't think create this quite large size buffer in main loop is a good choice. Any suggestion ?

Thanks a lot.

**[update]**

I checked this page [msdn-tcpclient.receivebuffersize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%5C) and found that the default size is 8192. Maybe in fact the default size will be different in different platform.

So I just make it safer like this,

```
var client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
var data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
client.GetStream().Read(data, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

better ?

But my problem is not how to new an enough buffer size for reading purpose, my problem is why ReceiveBufferSize is set to 65536 on Windows 8.1, especially I didn't set manually just keep it default, or otherwise how can it work on Windows 7.

Comment: There is never any reason to use a buffer that matches the internal operating default choice.  The correct size for the byte[] you pass to the Read() method is 4096 bytes.  Nobody can guess what "seemed have problems" could possibly mean.

Comment: You are doing something wrong!   What happens that should not happen.  What does not happen that should happen.  Maybe a bitta code?

Comment: You don't need to use the same size as that of receive buffer.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you explain or give a link that backs up the story about '4096' bytes for the TcpClient? I'm curious, that's all.

Comment: I guess we are NOT on the same page. I've updated the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it now, ReceiveBufferSize doesn't actually get the size of the buffer, its just a way for you to set a size manually first, and use it later.

Looks like we're gonna have to set a fixed size here, with no way to get the size of the buffer before it's reading.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivebuffersize?view=net-5.0